# Read a file in such a way that other processes are not prevented from modifying it

Tags: c#, windows, file-io

I need to continuously read a log file to detect certain patterns.  How can do so without interfering with file operations that the log writer operation needs to perform?

The log writer process, in addition to writing logs, periodically moves the file to another location (one it reaches certain size).

With the way I read the file, the log writer app fails to move the file.  I played with various FileShare options to no avail.

Here's simplified version of my code:

```
 using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\in.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Delete))
        { 
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader(stream);
            while (true)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(".. " + tr.ReadLine());
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

        }
```

Comment: " the log writer app fails to move the file" -- you want to keep a reader open on a file that's getting moved?

Comment: I want to keep reading as long as the file is available. I have no control over when/how the logging app moves the file.  Ideally, I would get an exception when the file is moved and I start reading the new log file from that point on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `FileShare.ReadWrite | FileShare.Delete`.

But if the file is deleted (moved) then I think your reading will fail.

Answer (score 2):

You are keeping the file open all the time, not only when there are changes to read.

I think a better approach would be to use a [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to monitor the file for changes and then open the file when changed and read in the new data. If the file is only appended to, you can keep track of how long you have processed the file and immediately seek to that position when you've opened the file.

Comment: If this is a moderately (or heavily) used log file (which I suspect it might be) then this will trigger constantly.  Say this file is getting written to it 1000 lines/second...

Comment: @anders Then he has the same problem that maybe a writer want to move that file when a reader read.

Comment: Like Joe mentioned, this being a log file, gets updated constantly.